# Get the commits made by specific authors (more than one)

Tags: git, commit

If I want to get `Alice`'s commits I use `git log --author 'Alice'`. But what if I want to include there `Bob`'s commits as well?

I tried the following:

```
git log --author 'Alice|Bob'
git log --author 'Alice,Bob'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with the same argument multiple times:

```
git log --author 'alice' --author 'bob'
```

edit: 
If Git is compiled with the right flags (USE_LIBPCRE) you can pass the option `--perl-regexp` so the pattern for search is interpreted as a regular expression:

```
git log --perl-regexp --author 'alice|bob'
```

...Found more:
Git interprets all patterns in the options as regex. Only if you want to use Perl compatible regex you need the option `--perl-regexp`. 
But if you want to use normal regex, you have to escape the "or":

```
git log --author 'alice\|bob'
```

Comment: Oh, never thought I could provide duplicated options to git! :) Thanks! Is it possible to specify it into one option? Anyway, this is the correct answer. :)

Comment: Do you have a GitHub account? If you like, I will add you as contributor in the [`git-stats-importer`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats-importer) project–it's part of the [`git-stats 2.0.0`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats/pull/47) release. :)